# SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex is providing wrong results for SOLR master-slave setup

Tags: solr, content-search, sitecore-api, indexing

Our custom indexes have primary (`search_index`) and Secondary (`search_index_rebuild`) cores which are pointing differently in master and slave servers as we are using `SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex`. Due to this mismatch, some of the products are not coming in the live site if those products are only present in one of the custom index cores.

Example: if any product is present only in one of the custom indexes core such as in Master SOLR Server the product is present only in `search_index` (Primary core) and `search_index` is pointing to `search_index_rebuild` core then the product is coming in the search result.

In the SOLR slave server, the `search_index` is also pointing to the `search_index_rebuild` instance but giving a different document count/ Last Modified date which is not providing the product result

```
ex: Master server: search_index (20k doc) & search_index_rebuild(10k)
Solr slave server: search_index (10k doc) & search_index_rebuild(20k)
```

Version:

Solr version: `7.2.1`

Sitecore version: `9.1.0`

Please let us know how we can resolve this or adjust this `SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex` functionality for our SOLR `Master-Slave` setup so that it will always provide us the same results.

We don't want to use `SolrCloud`.

[image]

search_index solrconfig.xml in Slave server:

[image]

search_index_rebuild solrconfig.xml in Slave server:
[image]

**Master server search_index and search_index_rebuild:**

[image]

[image]

**Slave server search_index and search_index_rebuild:**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When a core rebuild is initiated and you have `SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex` configured, the non active core is used to rebuild the index. When the rebuild is completed a swap command is sent to solr, after which each core will be known by the name of the other, after the swap.

You can trigger this manually via solr dashboards using command below:

```
admin/cores?action=SWAP&core=core-name&other=other-core-name
```

This command effectively updates the core.properties file with a latest update date and also changes (i.e. after first rebuild on search_index):

```
name=search_index_rebuid
```

If you have master/slave configured correctly in solr, then the changes mentioned above should then be exactly mirrored to the slave solr role.

Please check on your solr servers what is shown in core.properties (name=) for both main and rebuild cores, then compare to compare this matches on slave.

Also please check that both CA and CD sitecore roles have the same `SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex` config. I'm wondering if maybe CD has original (non switch) and could maybe just always point to search_index even if not the latest.

Useful references:
https://soyouwannasolrandsitecore.wordpress.com/2020/04/07/finding-the-active-solr-core/

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/switch-solr-indexes.html

https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/coreadmin-api.html

Comment: The main issue is SwitchOnREbuildSolrSearchIndex is doing the swap but whenever in Master server the search_index points to the search_index_rebuild and in Slave server if we have exactly same index pointing (ie. search_index points to search_index_rebuild) then search_index in slave shows the different number of records (which are present of search_index_rebuild in master).

Comment: For example: 20k docs are present when search_index is pointing to search_index_rebuild and 10k docs are present search_index_rebuild when it is pointing to search_index after swap in Master server. But in slave server after index replication 10k docs are present when search_index is pointing to search_index_rebuild data folder and 10k docs are present in search_index_rebuild when it is pointing to search_index.  Even after swap index datadir pointing is same in both Master Slave servers but still slave search_index is showing different results than Master

Comment: Can you share the replication section within your solrconfig.xml?

Specifically look to confirm <str name="masterUrl">https://your-domain-name.com:8983/solr/${solr.core.name}</str>

Comment: @DeanOBien Please check the below link for configuration details: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/34235/in-solr-master-slave-configuration-custom-indexes-are-getting-out-of-sync-someti/34249?noredirect=1#comment49821_34249

Comment: @DeanOBien I have attached the screenshot of solrconfig.xml of replication section in the post. Please find the SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex config screenshot as well.

Comment: If you publish an item or trigger a reindex, the lastModified property should be updated on search_index on the master. Do you see the exact same update on the slave? Is this production? If not - suggest deleting server/solr/search_index/data folder (and same from slave) and then restarting the solr service. Within seconds after restart the data should be replicated.

Comment: @DeanOBien I have attached the indexing screenshots on the post for both Master and SLave. You can see the LastModified date is same in both but then the instance/data/index folder path on slave search_index is different than the master.

Comment: But if the instance/data/index folder path is same on both Master and Slave (search_index points to search_index_rebuild) then the document count and modified date get differents in slave search_index which is the mail issue.

Comment: The images you have shared show exactly what I would expect. Master coreX = Slave coreX. The path in the slave will always point to same place, only master changes. Please can you trigger rebuild and show the problem you are reffering too.